# How to take a string split it into each character using Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm creating a C++ program where an individual enters their name as a string and the program outputs statements depending on the letters each name contains.

For example if a person has the letter "y" in their name, it should display a certain statement, but if they have "a" and "y", the statement should be different.

This program can be similar to numerology, where if you have certain letters in your name, it should output a given statement.

In order for me to do this, I need to know how I can take a string from the >user input and see each character separately. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to take a string from user input? What kind of string (char[] or std::string)? Do you know how to iterate over it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but this should help.

Think of a string as an array of chars. If you have a string,

```
string entry = "John Smith";
```

And you call

```
cout << entry[0];
```

entry[0] will return the first character in entry, 'J'.

With this knowledge, you should be able to take a name entry, and use if statements to test for letters in the string.

```
string entry;
cout << "What is your name?" << endl;


// Sets entry equal to what is typed in:

getline(cin,entry);



//Tests for letters:

if (entry[0] == 'J' && entry[1] == 'o') {

    cout << "Oh, your name starts with J, and the second letter is o" << endl;

}

else if (entry[0] == 'J') {

    cout << "Oh, your name starts with J and the second letter is not o." << endl;

}
```

There are no limits at this point to what you can do with the if statements. If you want to find a certain letter anywhere in the string instead of a certain position, use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < entry.size(); i++) {

    if (entry[i] == 'a') {

        cout << "Oh, there's an a somewhere in your name." << endl;

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!